# Prove T is continuous and open map

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

$X$ and $Y$ is topological vector spaces.

$T$ is linear map between this two spaces.
Also given that $ker(T)$ is closed and $Y$ is finite dimensional. We have to show that $T$ is continuous and open map.

I have already shown that $T$ is continuous. Without using the fact that $Y$ is finite dimensional. If I able to show $T$ is continuous linear map from that we can conclude that $T$ is bounded in some neighborhood $V$ of zero. From that we can say $T$ is open map. That is there is an open set contains in the $T(X)$.

I don't understand where we required the fact that $Y$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: If $T$ is also  surjective then it is an open map. Otherwise it is not open.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes. But how to show that from the fact finite dimensionality?

Comment: The case when $Y$ is one-dimensional is here. Adapt the same proof. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288855/nonconstant-linear-functional-on-a-topological-vector-space-is-an-open-mapping