# Non continuous linear operator image of ball

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X, \Vert . \Vert)$ be a normed space with $\dim X = \infty$.

Show that if $f: X \rightarrow R$ is linear and not continuous, then

$$f(B_X(x_0, r)) = \mathbb{R} \quad \forall x_0 \in X, \forall r > 0$$
where $B_X(x_0, r)$ is the open ball with center $x_0$, and radius $r$.

If $f$ is linear and not continuous then it is not bounded. In particular, $f(B_x(x_0, r))$ is not bounded (?). Why it is necessarily $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Hint: You can make $f(x)$ arbitrarily large for $x \in B_X(x_0, r)$. What can you say about $f(\lambda x)$ for $\lambda \in [-1, 1]$?

Comment: Even more simply, $\Bbb{R}$ is a one-dimensional space, and $\operatorname{range} f$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}$. What are the possible subspaces?

Comment: Here are postings in MSE ask and answer your question: [exaple 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/671043/121671), [example 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/288855/121671) this one deals with openness of linear functionals, one solution  deals with bounded and unbounded cases separately, the later case answers your question.